# SQL count occurrences without counting duplicates in another column

Tags: sql, proc-sql

I have a table:

```
Date       | ID | Company | Click 
-----------+----+---------+--------
01/01/2021 | 01 | Us      | 1
01/01/2021 | 01 | Us      | 1
01/01/2021 | 01 | Other   | 1
01/01/2021 | 02 | Us      | 0 
01/01/2021 | 02 | Other   | 0
02/01/2021 | 03 | Us      | 1 
02/01/2021 | 03 | Us      | 1 
02/01/2021 | 04 | Us      | 0
```

I want to group by date and count: how many different IDs there are per day, how many **unique** IDs have `clicked=1` and `Company="Us"`

My current code is:

```
create table grouped as 
select date
, count(distinct ID) as ID_count
, sum(case when company="Us" and clicked=1 then 1 else 0 end) as Click_count
from have 
group by 1
```

The result should look like:

```
Date       | ID_count | Click_count
-----------+----------+------------
01/01/2021 | 2        | 1
02/01/2021 | 2        | 1
```

You'll notice that my code counts duplicated ID's, so the `click_count` column takes the value 2 in both dates. How can I fix that?

Comment: Actually, your query returns `Click_count = 1`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ef22e8/10 (executed on PostgreSQL).
Please don't use `group by 1`. Use `group by date` instead.

Comment: Please tag your database

Answer (score 1):

You should use `COUNT()` to count the distinct `ID`s with a `CASE` expression:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN company = 'Us' AND clicked = 1 THEN ID END) AS click_count
```

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL solution using `filter` conditional aggregation:

```sql
select date, 
       count(distinct id) id_count,
       count(distinct id) filter (where click = 1 and company = 'Us') click_count 
from the_table
group by date;
```

If your database lacks the conditional aggregation `filter` capability then a scalar subquery - an alternative of @forpas suggestion - will do.

```sql
select date, 
       count(distinct id) id_count,
       (
         select count(distinct id) 
         from the_table
         where click = 1 and company = 'Us' and date = t.date
       ) click_count 
from the_table t
group by date;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7b6ff/1)